# firebase function is not work in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am facing an error while using firebase with my React JS project first time. when I am using the firebase.database() it gives an error I am trying to firebase function react js I am trying one logic but it is not working the way I want it to be. I am using the home.js file  I am using a functional component My code in home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import ImgSliderr from './ImgSliderr'
import Viewerss from './Viewerss'
import Movies from './Movies'
import dbConfig from '../Firebase'  

function Home() {

  useEffect(()=>{
    dbConfig.Collection("movies").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let tempMovie = snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>{
      console.log(doc.data());

      return{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
       })
       console.log(tempMovie);

    })
    console.log(db)
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container>
        <ImgSliderr />
        <Viewerss/>
        <Movies/>
   </Container>
  )
}

export default 
Home

const Container  = styled.main`
  min-height:calc(100vh - 70px);
  padding : 24px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;

  &:before {
    background: url("../images/images/home-background.png")  center center cover  no-repeat fixed; 
    content: "";
    position: absolute  ;
    TOP: 0;
    left: 0;
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 0;
    z-index:-1;
   `
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnhw8.png
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `console.log(db)` is going to crash your app because you don't have. a `db` variable to log...